# Query performance issue with "Contains" in Linq to entity framework query

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I am working with entityframework 4.0. I have used conatins query for a entity table to check agains the list of ids. e.g

```
List<int> lstIds = lstComapreObjaects.select(c => c.Id).ToList();
IQueryable<ResultedEntity> qry = from su in Context.ResultedEntites 
                                 where lstIds.Contains(su.Id ?? 0) == true
List<ResultedEntity> lst = qry.ToList();
```

This works fine but the problem is it takes around 3-4 mins to execute the query...

So my question is how to improve the performance???
can i make join between entity and a generic list???

Comment: A list is not a suitable data structure for checking if something is contained in there. You would typically use a HashSet or a Dictionary for that.

Comment: How many items do you have in `lstIds` and in `ResultedEntities` table? Do you have index on Id column in the database?

Comment: Why do you do a select in memory, when your database should be responsible for that?

Comment: Yes, not enough information.  How many ID's are you passing?  Where does the list of IDs come from?  Param limit for SPs (and queries, i assume, is 2100).  If over that, it would prob bring the entire table down.  If not, maybe it takes forever to prepare a 2000 param query.   Ignore that about the hashset or dictionary.  How on earth would you use either of those for a single value, not a NV pair?  And they don't play with linq, anyway.

Comment: Thank u guys for ur valuable time anad advice i have manged to solve it on my own...i taken the tables in to join and passed the smaller amount to check in conatains list...

Comment: Yes there is performance issue with the "contains" in Linq to entityframwork as the contains list grows it will slow down your query result..so it is better to keep the list short as possible or avoid to use it...

Comment: For those friend who were interested in data amount : Total Ids that List lstIds contains is 5267 and Final resulted list contains 12000 Objects....